# Interpreting Javascript objects with literal notation/Object initializers in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I made a PHP script to get an object initializer from a remote website using curl an the object looks like this

```
{'403' : {'3' : { qin : 144, qout : 52}, '4' : { qin : 143, qout : 86}, '5' : { qin : 144, qout : 79}, '6' : { qin : 143, qout : 93}, '7' : { qin : 144, qout : 78} }
```

¿Is there a function in PHP to interpret this or i need to use regular expressions?

Is not JSON valid but it's a valid Javascipt literal notation.

Comment: It would be valid JSON if you wrapped all the properties with "

Comment: @Kiyura: It would not be because there are unquoted property names as well. Even if it were this would be a hacky and brittle solution that I 'd hate to see anywhere near the code I 'm working with.

Comment: And using regexes is going to be less hacky somehow? :P The problem here is the terrible input. It's impossible to make it robust because it's unclear what the requirements are.

Comment: @Kiyura: I 'm not sure how regexes got brought into the picture -- I certainly didn't bring them. The most robust would of course be a full-blown parser, which the OP understandably does not want to write. That's the point of the question.

Comment: Jon is right, and as i see the best method would be to write or find a good parser. By now i found this old J4P5 script that interprets all objects i tryed, so i'm going to find the js_literal_object and see how it works. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Not to be used in production instead try and get a valid json output***

```
$json = "{'403' : {'3' : { qin : 144, qout : 52}, '4' : { qin : 143, qout : 86}, '5' : { qin : 144, qout : 79}, '6' : { qin : 143, qout : 93}, '7' : { qin : 144, qout : 78} }" ;

$json = preg_replace("/'(\w+)'/", '$1', $json); //remove all single quote
$json = preg_replace("/\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/", ' "$1"', $json);
$json .= "}"; // Missing End

var_dump($json,json_decode($json));
```

Output

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public '403' => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public '3' => 
        object(stdClass)[3]
          public 'qin' => string '144' (length=3)
          public 'qout' => string '52' (length=2)
      public '4' => 
        object(stdClass)[4]
          public 'qin' => string '143' (length=3)
          public 'qout' => string '86' (length=2)
      public '5' => 
        object(stdClass)[5]
          public 'qin' => string '144' (length=3)
          public 'qout' => string '79' (length=2)
      public '6' => 
        object(stdClass)[6]
          public 'qin' => string '143' (length=3)
          public 'qout' => string '93' (length=2)
      public '7' => 
        object(stdClass)[7]
          public 'qin' => string '144' (length=3)
          public 'qout' => string '78' (length=2
```

Comment: I got the point, but as the data can be decimal numbers or negative values i'd have to change the regex to something like this `"/'([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+)'/"` Thanks for your answer and if in a couple of days no one gives a better solution i'll accept it.